# get IDs from links categories

Tags: categories, taxonomy, get-bookmarks

How can I get the IDs of all my links categories?

I'm writting a plugin to bookmark more easy using `wp_insert_link()` function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ask [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) for the `'link_category'` and restrict the returned fields to IDs:

```
get_terms( 'link_category', array ( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
```